# Subreports show up on top of the page despite they are placed in the middle of the page

Tags: reporting-services, display, subreport

My problem is SSRS subreports showing up on top of the main report despite they are located somewhere close to the bottom of the page. The subreports don't have page headers and footers. The report shows ok in design time (VS2017). However, in the report server (SQLSERVER2012) the subreports show up on the header level of the main report. The interesting thing is that the main report is portrait design but subreports show up next to each other expanding towards the right-hand side of the page.

Due to the privacy issue, I can't post the picture of the reports here However I can illustrate with a small picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rGbs.png)

Comment: Are the subreports in a container of any kind (Tablix, rectangle etc) ? Have you specified the target server version correctly in your project properties?

Comment: @Pratham - ha, very funny.

Comment: I would try to recreate the report and see if the issue still exists. Just copy and past the objects. This looks abnormal and there may not be a way to fix it through editing the original. I've had other issues where charts got corrupted but couldn't fixed.